# JS dynamically get IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page I have a a couple of tables containing product information and their authors. I also have a div containing the hyperlinks for each author. Right now I'm linking the authors names to a hyperlink using javascript:

```
<script>
    onload = myfun;
    function myfun(){
        var show  =document.getElementById('2364').innerHTML;
        var link  = document.getElementsByClassName('2364');   
        var item  = link[0];  
        var item2 = link[1]; 
        document.getElementById('2364').innerHTML=item.outerHTML+'; '+item2.outerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

My problem is that I need to get the elements IDs dynamically and I am not sure how to go about this.

**EDIT:**

Smarty creates the html, here's a part of it:

```
<tr><td class="PLContent"><span class="manufacturer"><div id={$module_data.PRODUCTS_ID}>

<h3 id={php}echo $e++;{/php}>{$module_data.PRODUCTS_MANUFACTURER_NAME}{$MANUFACTURER_LINK}</h3></div></span>
```

Dynamic IDs means that when a user clicks on an author the page will be populated with different products and those products will have a different ID.

Comment: If you can group all the DIVs that you need by a class. Then you can just select every div that has the class associated with it. From those elements you can get the ID.

Comment: "get the elements IDs dynamically" — Based on what? "Dynamic" is not a useful word without context.

Comment: Can you please provide a more clear context?

Comment: using jqueary you can run "each" loop and het the id of all the div's

Comment: Sorry for asking this: But cant you simply do this in the template, instead of the client side? If you have the data in your system, you should be able to parse it from the server side?

Comment: @Olavxxx I tried that but couldn't get it to work. If a product has more than 1 author all of the authors are passed as one string. That's why I used php for exploding the array and assigning each item a class and so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys, they gave me some ideas. I managed to solve my problem in the following way:

1. Added an  element that contains only the products ID
2. Changed my code to this:

.

```
var t1 = document.getElementById('1').innerHTML;
var link = document.getElementsByClassName(t1);
document.getElementById(t1).innerHTML = link[0].outerHTML;
```

As I have 10 products per page I'll write this function for each product changing the IDs. It may not be very neat but it's doing the job.

HTML:

```
<div id={$module_data.PRODUCTS_ID}>
    <p>{$module_data.PRODUCTS_MANUFACTURER_NAME}</p>
    <p id={php}echo $e++;{/php}>{$module_data.PRODUCTS_ID}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can add a class name to your elements and then get all IDs (assuming your are familiar with jQuery).

```
<tr><td class="PLContent"><span class="manufacturer"><div class="mydiv" id={$module_data.PRODUCTS_ID}>
    <h3 class="myh3" id={php}echo $e++;{/php}>{$module_data.PRODUCTS_MANUFACTURER_NAME}{$MANUFACTURER_LINK}</h3></div></span>
```

To get IDs:

```
$(".mydiv").each(function() { alert($(this).attr("id"); });
```

or

```
$(".myh3").each(function() { alert($(this).attr("id"); });
```

Comment: Just include latest version of jquery in your page header and use this.

Comment: This is less efficient than getting the pattern directly. Let's say you have thousands of elements to match the class. You have to check each of them individually. DOM-matching will be significantly faster and will instantly give the needed result. Especially when do that check on-the-fly after page load (e.a. on Hover).

Comment: I'm not sure efficiency matters here, specially 'thousands of elements'. By the way, let's see which is suitable for him.

Comment: StackOverflow isnt a competition. I have removed my answer. Let's hope the OP doesn't use this for mobile devices.

Comment: I'm sorry, but all all I'm saying is efficiency is not important always. Sometime simple codes work better. After all, you should not remove your answer, Add it again, i'm not fighting dude.